# Construction of Dirichlet distribution with Gamma distribution

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis, gamma-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

> Let $X_1,\dots,X_{k+1}$ be mutually independent random variables, each having a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha_i,i=1,2,\dots,k+1$ show that $Y_i=\frac{X_i}{X_1+\cdots+X_{k+1}},i=1,\dots,k$, have a joint ditribution as $\text{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k;\alpha_{k+1})$

Joint pdf of $(X_1,\dots,X_{k+1})=\frac{e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_i}x_1^{\alpha_1-1}\dots x_{k+1}^{\alpha_{k+1}-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)\dots \Gamma(\alpha_{k+1})}$.Then to find joint pdf of $(Y_1,\dots,Y_{k+1})$ I can not find jacobian i.e.$J(\frac{x_1,\dots,x_{k+1}}{y_1,\dots,y_{k+1}})$

Comment: Have a look at pages 13-14 of this [document](http://www.ee.washington.edu/research/guptalab/publications/UWEETR-2010-0006.pdf).

Comment: @Procrastinator Thank you very much your document is best answer for my question.

Comment: @Procrastinator - perhaps you should put this as an answer, since the OP is happy with it, and add a couple of sentences so you don't trip the "we want more than one-sentence answer" warning?

Comment: That document now is a non-answer because it's a 404.

Comment: Wayback machine to the rescue: [pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20121021045524/http://www.ee.washington.edu:80/research/guptalab/publications/UWEETR-2010-0006.pdf)

Comment: Updated link: https://vannevar.ece.uw.edu/techsite/papers/documents/UWEETR-2010-0006.pdf

Answer (score 49):

Jacobians--the absolute determinants of the change of variable function--appear formidable and can be complicated.  Nevertheless, they are an essential and unavoidable part of the calculation of a multivariate change of variable.  It would seem there's nothing for it but to write down a $k+1$ by $k+1$ matrix of derivatives and do the calculation.

**There's a better way.**  It's shown at the end in the "Solution" section.  Because the purpose of this post is to introduce statisticians to what may be a new method for many, much of it is devoted to explaining the machinery behind the solution.  This is the algebra of *differential forms*.  (Differential forms are the things that one integrates in multiple dimensions.)  A detailed, worked example is included to help make this become more familiar.

---

#### Background

Over a century ago, mathematicians developed the theory of [differential algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) to work with the "higher order derivatives" that occur in multi-dimensional geometry.  The determinant is a special case of the basic objects manipulated by such algebras, which typically are *alternating multilinear forms*.  **The beauty of this lies in how simple the calculations can become.**

Here's all you need to know.

1. A *differential* is an expression of the form "$dx_i$".  It is the concatenation of "$d$" with any variable name.
2. A *one-form* is a linear combination of differentials, such as $dx_1+dx_2$ or even $x_2 dx_1 - \exp(x_2) dx_2$.  That is, the coefficients are *functions* of the variables.
3. Forms can be "multiplied" using a *wedge product*, written $\wedge$.  This product is anti-commutative (also called *alternating*): for any two one-forms $\omega$ and $\eta$,

   $$\omega \wedge \eta = -\eta \wedge \omega.$$

This multiplication is linear and associative: in other words, it works in the familiar fashion.  An immediate consequence is that $\omega \wedge \omega = -\omega \wedge \omega$, implying the square of any one-form is always zero.  That makes multiplication extremely easy!

4. For the purposes of manipulating the integrands that appear in probability calculations, an expression like $dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{k+1}$ can be understood as $|dx_1\wedge dx_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{k+1}|$.
5. When $y = g(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is a function, then its differential is given by differentiation:

   $$dy = dg(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) dx_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) dx_n.$$

**The connection with Jacobians is this:** the Jacobian of a transformation $(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = F(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (f_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n), \ldots, f_n(x_1, \ldots, x_n))$ is, up to sign, simply the coefficient of $dx_1\wedge \dots \wedge dx_n$ that appears in computing

$$dy_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy_n = df_1(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\wedge \cdots \wedge df_n(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$

after expanding each of the $df_i$ as a linear combination of the $dx_j$ in rule (5).

---

#### Example

The simplicity of this definition of a Jacobian is appealing.  Not yet convinced it's worthwhile?  Consider the well-known problem of converting two-dimensional integrals from Cartesian coordinates $(x, y)$ to polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, where $(x,y) = (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta))$.  The following is an utterly mechanical application of the preceding rules, where "$(*)$" is used to abbreviate expressions that will obviously disappear by virtue of rule (3), which implies $dr\wedge dr = d\theta\wedge d\theta = 0$.

$$\eqalign{
dx dy &= |dx\wedge dy| = |d(r\cos(\theta)) \wedge d(r\sin(\theta))| \\
  &= |(\cos(\theta)dr - r\sin(\theta)d\theta) \wedge (\sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta| \\
  &= |(*)dr\wedge dr + (*) d\theta\wedge d\theta - r\sin(\theta)d\theta\wedge \sin(\theta)dr + \cos(\theta)dr \wedge r\cos(\theta) d\theta| \\
  &= |0 + 0 + r\sin^2(\theta) dr\wedge d\theta + r\cos^2(\theta) dr\wedge d\theta| \\
  &= |r(\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta)) dr\wedge d\theta)| \\
  &= r\ dr d\theta
}.$$

The point of this is the ease with which such calculations can be performed, without messing about with matrices, determinants, or other such multi-indicial objects.  You just multiply things out, remembering that wedges are anti-commutative.  It's *easier* than what is taught in high school algebra.

---

#### Preliminaries

**Let's see this differential algebra in action.**  In this problem, the PDF of the joint distribution of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{k+1})$ is the product of the individual PDFs (because the $X_i$ are assumed to be independent).  In order to handle the change to the variables $Y_i$ we must be explicit about the *differential elements* that will be integrated.  These form the term $dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{k+1}$.  Including the PDF gives the *probability element*

$$\eqalign{
f_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\alpha})dx_1 \cdots dx_{k+1} &\propto \left(x_1^{\alpha_1-1}\exp\left(-x_1\right)\right)\cdots \left(x_{k+1}^{\alpha_{k+1}-1}\exp\left(-x_{k+1}\right) \right)dx_1 \cdots dx_{k+1} \\
&= x_1^{\alpha_1-1}\cdots x_{k+1}^{\alpha_{k+1}-1}\exp\left(-\left(x_1+\cdots+x_{k+1}\right)\right)dx_1 \cdots dx_{k+1}.
}$$

(The normalizing constant has been ignored; it will be recovered at the end.)

Staring at the definitions of the $Y_i$ a few seconds ought to reveal the utility of introducing the new variable

$$Z = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{k+1},$$

giving the relationships

$$X_i = Y_i Z.$$

This suggests making the change of variables $x_i \to y_i z$ in the probability element.  The intention is to retain the first $k$ variables $y_1, \ldots, y_k$ along with $z$ and then integrate out $z$.  **To do so, we have to re-express all the $dx_i$ in terms of the new variables.**  This is the heart of the problem.  It's where the differential algebra takes place.  To begin with,

$$dx_i = d(y_i z) = y_i dz + z dy_i.$$

Note that since $Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_{k+1}=1$, then

$$0 = d(1) = d(y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_{k+1}) = dy_1 + dy_2 + \cdots + dy_{k+1}.$$

Consider the one-form

$$\omega = dx_1 + \cdots + dx_k = z(dy_1 + \cdots + dy_k) + (y_1+\cdots + y_k) dz.$$

It appears in the differential of the last variable:

$$\eqalign{
dx_{k+1} &= z dy_{k+1} + y_{k+1}dz \\
     &= -z(dy_1 + \cdots + dy_k) + (1-y_1-\cdots -y_k)dz \\
     &= dz - \omega.
}$$

The value of this lies in the observation that

$$dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_k \wedge \omega = 0$$

because, when you expand this product, there is one term containing $dx_1 \wedge dx_1 = 0$ as a factor, another containing  $dx_2 \wedge dx_2 = 0$, and so on: *they all disappear.*  Consequently,

$$\eqalign{
dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_k \wedge dx_{k+1} &= dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_k \wedge dz - dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_k \wedge \omega \\
&= dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_k \wedge dz.
}$$

Whence (because all products $dz\wedge dz$ disappear),

$$\eqalign{
dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{k+1} &= (z dy_1 + y_1 dz) \wedge \cdots \wedge (z dy_k + y_k dz) \wedge dz \\
&= z^k dy_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy_k \wedge dz.
}$$

**The Jacobian is simply $|z^k| = z^k$,** the coefficient of the differential product on the right hand side.

---

#### Solution

The transformation $(x_1, \ldots, x_k, x_{k+1})\to (y_1, \ldots, y_k, z)$ is one-to-one: its inverse is given by $x_i = y_i z$ for $1\le i\le k$ and $x_{k+1} = z(1-y_1-\cdots-y_k)$.  Therefore we don't have to fuss any more about the new probability element; it simply is

$$\eqalign{
&(z y_1)^{\alpha_1-1}\cdots (z y_k)^{\alpha_k-1}\left(z(1-y_1-\cdots-y_k)\right)^{\alpha_{k+1}-1}\exp\left(-z\right)|z^k dy_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy_k \wedge dz| \\
&= \left(z^{\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{k+1}-1}\exp\left(-z\right) dz\right)\left( y_1^{\alpha_1-1} \cdots y_k^{\alpha_k-1}\left(1-y_1-\cdots-y_k\right)^{\alpha_{k+1}-1}dy_1 \cdots dy_k\right).
}$$

That is manifestly a product of a Gamma$(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{k+1})$ distribution (for $Z$) and a Dirichlet$(\mathbf\alpha)$ distribution (for $(Y_1,\ldots, Y_k)$).  In fact, since the original normalizing constant must have been a product of $\Gamma(\alpha_i)$, we deduce immediately that the new normalizing constant must be divided by $\Gamma(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{k+1})$, enabling the PDF to be written

$$f_\mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{\alpha}) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{k+1})}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\cdots\Gamma(\alpha_{k+1})}\left( y_1^{\alpha_1-1} \cdots y_k^{\alpha_k-1}\left(1-y_1-\cdots-y_k\right)^{\alpha_{k+1}-1}\right).$$

Comment: Not sure but I think there's a typo in the last parital derivative in rule nr. 5 and also after "Consequently," where there should be $dz$ instead of $z$?

Comment: @Dancing Thank you for those comments.  Those are indeed both typos and I'll fix them right away.

Comment: +1 This post not only answers the question, but allows readers to learn how to derive similar results on a large family of problems thankw to covering the preliminaries.

Comment: For a longer introduction of differential forms see [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL22w63XsKjqzQZtDZO_9s2HEMRJnaOTX7) by Michael Penn.