# Joint distribution given normalized gamma distributed components

Tags: probability, distributions

Consider $N = 2^{n}$ random variables $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{N}$, such that for each $i \in [N]$,

$$X_{i} \sim \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}, 2^{-n+1}\right). $$

We are also given that
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{N}X_{i} = 1$$

What is the pdf for the joint distribution for the $N$-tuple $(X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots X_{N})$? Does it follow a Dirichlet distribution? Note that the random variables are identically distributed but not independent.

Comment: I can't be: the marginals of a Dirichlet have Beta distributions.

Comment: What is the pdf for the joint distribution then? Can it be found out from the given information?

Comment: If the $X_i$'s are iid Gamma's, their sum cannot be one. Do you mean the distribution of the vector conditional to the sum being equal to one?

Comment: The random variables are identically distributed, but not necessarily independent. So, the sum can be $1$ right?

Comment: I guess I do mean something like "the distribution of the vector conditional to the sum being equal to one."

Comment: The joint distribution does not have a PDF because it is singular.  Perhaps you would like the PDF of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{N-1})$ instead?  For a standard relationship between Gamma variates and the Dirichlet distribution, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36093.  And for a very closely related question, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252692.  (Notice that when you take sums of your $X_i$ in disjoint pairs you have $N/2$ exponential variables, exactly as posited there.)

Comment: A few confusions: why is the joint distribution singular? In the second link, you seemed to imply that the $N$-variate distribution is a symmetric Dirichlet. If that is so, does that not mean that the $N$-variate distribution has a PDF? Also, in the second link, the $X_{i}$s seemed to have been independent. Will that be a problem for my case? Finally, what is the PDF for the $(N-1)$-variate distribution, like you said? Will it also be a Dirichlet (I can't immediately relate the same proof techniques as the random variables are no longer independent.)

Comment: Also, in the second link you provided each $X_{i}$ had an exponential distribution, whereas for me, I have a Gamma distribution. How will that change the final result?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36093/construction-of-dirichlet-distribution-with-gamma-distribution/154298#154298.