# The distribution of $\frac{nX_{(1)}}{\sum_{j=1}^nX_j}$, where $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid from an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, random-variable

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid from a continuous distribution with pdf $$f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(x-\theta)},\:\: x>\theta,\: \theta \in \mathbb{R}$$

What is the distribution of $\frac{nX_{(1)}}{\sum_{j=1}^nX_j}$? Note $X_{(1)} = \min(X_1,..,X_n)$.

Note: I am trying to define the rejection region of an LRT and I am stuck at the point where I'd have to determine the distribution of the ratio of random variables above. My major challenge is a result of the fact that the numerator and the denominator are not independent.

Comment: You could use the fact that $X_{(1)}$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n (X_j-X_{(1)})$ are independent, with well-known distributions of their own (Typo in the pdf; should be $x>\theta$).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252692/distribution-given-sum/252784#252784 shows you how to find this.

Comment: Check `dirichlet` as a keyword