# Find the distribution of $Y-X|X=x$

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, conditioning

The conditional distribution of $Y|X=x$ is Normal$(x,1)$. The marginal distribution of $X$ is Normal$(0,1)$

> Find the distribution of $Y-X|X=x$.

I notice that since the conditional distribution of $Y$ has $x$ as a parameter, this implies that $X$ and $Y$ are **not** independent. Which is unusual because in my courses the theory has been mainly about independent random variables.

Anyway, I proceed by doing what seems natural. Let $Z = Y-X$. Then I need to find $$f_{Z|X=x}(z|x)=\frac{f(z,x)}{f_X(x)}$$

To find $f(z,x)$ I need to know $f_Y(y)$.

$$f_{Y|X=x}(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac12(y-x)^2)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$

This implies that $$f(x,y) =f_X(x)\cdot f_{Y|X=x}(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12x^2\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac12(y-x)^2\right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac12(x^2 +(y-x)^2) \right)$$

Then according to Wolfram, $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left( -y^2/4\right)$

I thought that I could find $f(x,y)$, then create another variable to use the Jacobian method to find $f(z,x)$. But since $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, I have no idea how to find $f(x,y)$.

Would like some guidance for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the _conditional_ distribution of $Y-X$ _given_ that $X = x$ just the distribution of $Y-x$ which is $N(0,1)$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I feel like in this case $Y-x$ would be Normal with mean $x$ and I don't know about the variance because $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. Don't you add (or subtract) the means? And if the random variables are independent you can sum their variances.

Comment: You should have something better than feelings to go on. Everything Dilip said is correct

Comment: The accepted answer references the first comment here, but I think there is a word or phrase missing from the comment. At least it is hard for me to parse. @DilipSarwate, can you please clarify your comment here?

Comment: @ChadSexington The _conditional_ distribution of $Y-X$ given that $X=x$ is the same as the _conditional_ distribution of $Y-x$ given that $X=x$.  But, given that $X=x$, the _conditional_ distribution of $Y$ is $N(x,1)$ and so the _conditional_ distribution of $Y-x$ conditioned on $X=x$ has mean $0$,  no? and variance $1$? Going back to what the first sentence is saying, we conclude that for every real number $x$, the conditional distribution of $Y-X$ conditioned on $X=x$ is $N(0,1)$ which suggests to me that $X$ and $Y-X$ are actually iid $N(0,1)$ random variables, but ymmv.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I agree! I think your answer is very thorough. I am suggesting that there is simply a word missing. I think an "is" is needed after the $X=x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *have* found $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ correctly.

- Now observe that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a *bivariate* Gaussian density by expanding out the terms in that exponent, and then writing them in the standard form of the bivariate Gaussian density. Note down the values of the 5 parameters (means, variances and correlation coefficient) of this bivariate Gaussian density for later use.
- Next, observe that since $(X,Y)$ is bivariate Gaussian, so is $(X,Y-X) = (X,Z)$ bivariate Gaussian.
- Finally, note that for bivariate Gaussian $(X,Z)$, the conditional density of $Z$ given that $X=x$ is Gaussian.

In these last two steps, there is no need to *write* out the densities,
or use Jacobians or something like that. Just use the 
known formulas that relate the five parameters of bivariate Gaussian $(X,Y-X)$ to the known five parameters of bivariate Gaussian $(X,Y)$ 
(e.g. $\mu_{Y-X} = \mu_Y - \mu_X$, $\sigma_{Y-X}^2 = \sigma_Y^2 + \sigma_X^2 -2 \rho_{Y,X}\sigma_Y\sigma_X$, etc) and then the known formulas for the mean and variance of the conditional Gaussian density of $Z$ given $X = x$ when $(X,Z)$ is bivariate Gaussian. If you do everything correctly, you should get the answer that I suggested in my hint on your question.

---

**Comment:** For *arbitrary* random variables $X$ and $Y$ (not necessarily bivariate Gaussian), it is true that the *conditional* distribution of $Y-X$ given that $X=x$ is the same as the *conditional*
distribution of $Y-x$ given that $X = x$. The basic idea is that since we are assuming that the event $X=x$ has occurred, then $Y-X$ must have value $Y-x$ under this assumption, and so the conditional distribution of $Y-X$ given that $X=x$ has occurred is the same as the conditional distribution of $Y-x$ given that $X = x$ has occurred.

As corroborative detail intended to give a touch of artistic verisimilitude to the otherwise bald and unconvincing narrative above, consider that if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables with joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, then 
$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X=x_0) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x_0,y)}{f_{X}(x_0)}$$
while the usual Jacobian method of random vector density transformation
gives
$$f_{X,Z}(x,z) = f_{X,Y-X}(x,z) = f_{X,Y}(x,z+x)\\
f_{X,\hat Z}(x,z) = f_{X,Y-x_0}(x,z) = f_{X,Y}(x,z+x_0)$$
and so
$$f_{Z\mid X}(z\mid X=x_0) = \frac{f_{X,Z}(x_0,z)}{f_{X}(x_0)}
= \frac{f_{X,Y}(x_0,z+x_0)}{f_{X}(x_0)}
= f_{Y\mid X}(z+x_0\mid X=x_0)\\
f_{\hat Z\mid X}(z\mid X=x_0) = \frac{f_{X,Y-x_0}(x_0,z)}{f_{X}(x_0)}
= \frac{f_{X,Y}(x_0,z+x_0)}{f_{X}(x_0)}
= f_{Y\mid X}(z+x_0\mid X=x_0)$$
that is,
$f_{Y-X\mid X}(z\mid X = x_0)$, the conditional density of $Z=Y-X$ conditioned on $X = x_0$ is the same as $f_{Y-x_0\mid X}(z\mid X = x_0)$,
the conditional density of $\hat Z = Y-x_0$ conditioned on $X = x_0$.

Comment: Expanding the exponent gives $2x^2 - 2xy + y^2$. Since $X$ is $N(0,1)$, we know that $\sigma_x = 1$ and $\mu_x=0$. But with those two values I can't reduce the standard form of the bivariate Gaussian to what I have.

Comment: @SOULed_Outt You computed the pdf of $Y$ from which you can deduce (I hope) that $\mu_Y = 0, \sigma_{Y}^2 = 2.$ So you have 4 of the five parameters already. Now, notice that the $2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma_X\sigma_Y$ that occurs somewhere in the bivariate Gaussian density formula happens to have value $2\pi$ in this case, which suggests that $\rho = \pm \cdots$. So, keep chugging away...

Comment: I thought my pdf of $Y$ was incorrect, so I didn't think to use the fact that it was $N(0,2)$ to save computational time (and lots of mistakes). I was wondering if you had any suggestions to text where I could practice with concepts like this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

We are given:
\begin{equation}
Y|X=x \sim N(x, 1) \;\mathrm{and}\; X \sim N(0, 1)
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
The goal is to find
\begin{equation}
(Y-X|X=x) \sim \;?.
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

With
\begin{equation}
Z=Y-X \tag{3},
\end{equation}
we are looking for the probability density $f_{Z|X=x}(z|x)$. We perform a coordinate transform to find,
\begin{equation}
f_{Z,X}(z,x)(dx \wedge dz) = f_{Z,X}(y-x,x)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} (dx \wedge dy) \equiv f_{Y,X}(y,x)(dx \wedge dy),
\end{equation}
where the $(dx \wedge dx)=0$ term has been dropped. From Eq. (3), $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=1$. Now we can write
\begin{equation}
f_{Z|X}(z|x)=\frac{f_{Z,X}(z,x)}{f_{X}(x)}=\frac{f_{Y,X}(y,x)}{f_{X}(x)}=f_{Y|X}(y|x)=f_{Y|X}(z+x|x)
\end{equation}

From Eq. (1) we have the conditional probability density
\begin{equation}
f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^2},
\end{equation} so plugging in $y=z+x$ gives
\begin{equation}
f_{Z|X}(z|x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{1}{2}z^2}.
\end{equation}
Which means that
\begin{equation}
(Y-X|X=x) = (Z|X=x) \sim N(0,1).
\end{equation}

If you're looking for a description of the "wedge" ($\wedge$) there is a really good description [in this Cross Validated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36093/construction-of-dirichlet-distribution-with-gamma-distribution/154298#154298).