# what is the relation between change of variables in probability and calculus?

Tags: probability, self-study, calculus

I want to know if the change of variables formula in probability is a special case
of the change of variables in calculus, or something different.

Trying to think for myself, first write the CoV for probability within informal derivation,
$$
   p(y)dy = p(x)dx  \quad\Rightarrow\quad p(y) = p(x) \left| \frac{dx}{dy} \right|
$$
and I believe we could add integration to make it look more like the calculus case, though the answer is one
$$
 \int p(y) \, dy = \int p(x) \left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right| \, dx = 1
$$

Now writing the CoV for calculus, mulitidimensional form, 
$$
\iint_\Omega f(g(p)) |J_g| \, dp = \iint_{g(\Omega)} f(p) \, dp
$$
and rewrite this to look like the probability case, $p\rightarrow x$
$$
\iint_\Omega f(y=g(x)) |J| \, dx = \iint_{g(\Omega)} f(x) \, dx
$$
move the $|J|$ to the other side, and name $f \rightarrow p$
$$
\iint_\Omega p(y) \, dx = \iint_{g(\Omega)} p(x) |J|^{-1} \, dx
$$

This does not quite look like the probability case, because on the left side it should be
$$
  \iint_\Omega p(y) \, \mathbf{d}y
$$
rather than
$$
  \iint_\Omega p(y) \, \mathbf{d}x
$$

Probably I made a mistake. Can anyone explain what the mistake is?

self studying

Comment: The change of variables formula of probability *is* that of Calculus: there is no difference whatsoever.  One rigorous way of approaching it is explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154298/919 using differential forms.

Comment: That link looks almost understandable, but I do not know differential forms.

Is it possible to comment on what is wrong with the informal derivation I gave above?  It tries to put the probability and calculus CoV in the same form, but fails.