Transforming variables within MCMC to get the prior distribution to match proposal
I'm doing Bayesian MCMC where I am proposing some weights, say, a_1:a_5 from a Dirichlet distribution to ensure summation to 1. However, the prior (Beta) distribution is on some calculation of these weights, b_1:b_5. It is my understanding that I should make a transformation. Below are the relationships between a and b:
a_1=b_1
a_2=(1-b_1)(b_2)
a_3=(1-b_1)(1-b_2)b_3
a_4=(1-b_1)(1-b_2)(1-b_3)b_4
a_5=(1-b_1)(1-b_2)(1-b_3)(1-b_4)b_5

I found the Jacobian to be: $(b_1 - 1)^4 \times (b_2 - 1)^3 \times (b_3 - 1)^2 \times (b_4 - 1)$
But I'm not sure of where to go from here. When finding the prior density, do I multiply the input by this Jacobian? Below is my R code as if I was ignoring the mismatch between prior and proposal.
  a<-rDirichlet.acomp(1,mcmc_chain_weights[i,1:5]*(tuning_parameter))
  b=rep(NA,5)
  b[1]<-a[1]
  b[2]<-a[2]/((1-b[1]))
  b[3]<-a[3]/((1-b[1])*(1-b[2]))
  b[4]<-a[4]/((1-b[1])*(1-b[2])*(1-b[3]))
  b[5]<-a[5]/((1-b[1])*(1-b[2])*(1-b[3])*(1-b[4]))
  
  Hastings_ratio<-L()*dbeta(b,1,tau)*dDirichlet(a_previous,alpha=a) / ...

Please note that tau is a constant and I left the likelihood function blank as it's irrelevant here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's a related question about reparametrization before sampling.

You might find the techniques illustrated in related questions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450621 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36093 to be helpful.

I got it. Thanks!
