# Conditional distribution of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I'm doing some self studying this, I got stuck on this question:

> Suppose $(X,Y,Z)'$ is normal with density
> \begin{equation*}
>     \begin{split}
>         C\cdot \text{exp}\{-\frac{1}{2}(4x^{2}+3y^{2}+5z^{2}+2xy+6xz+4zy)\},
>     \end{split}
> \end{equation*}
> where $C$ is a normalizing constant. Determine the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X+Z=1$ and $Y+Z$=0.

This is what I tried:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \mathbf{\mu}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
            0  \\
             0\\
             0
        \end{array}\right]\qquad \Lambda^{-1}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
             4& 1& 3 \\
             1& 3& 2\\
             3& 2& 5
        \end{array}\right],\qquad \\
\begin{array}{c}
         U=X  \\
         V=X+Z \\
   W=Y+Z \end{array} \\
        \mathbf{B}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
         U  \\
         V\\
         W
    \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
            1 & 0& 0 \\
           1  & 0& 1\\
           0& 1& 1
        \end{array}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{B\mu}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
            1 & 0& 0 \\
           1  & 0& 1\\
           0& 1& 1
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
            0  \\
             0\\
             0
        \end{array}\right]  =\left[\begin{array}{c}
            0  \\
             0\\
             0
        \end{array}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Lambda=\frac{1}{|\mathrm{det} \Lambda^{-1}|} \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
          \mathrm{det} \left|\begin{array}{cc}
               3 &2 \\
               2 &5
           \end{array}\right|=11 &\mathrm{det}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
               1 &2  \\
               3 &5
           \end{array}\right|=(-1)& \mathrm{det}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
               1 &3  \\
               3 &2
           \end{array}\right|=(-7) \\
            \mathrm{det}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
               1 &3 \\
               2 &5
           \end{array}\right|=(-1) & \mathrm{det}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
               4 &3  \\
               3 &5
           \end{array}\right|=11 &\mathrm{det}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
               4 &1  \\
               3 &2
           \end{array}\right|=5 \\
           \mathrm{det}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
               1 &3  \\
               3 &2
           \end{array}\right|=(-7) & \mathrm{det}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
               4&3 \\
               1 &2
           \end{array}\right|=5 & \mathrm{det}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
               4 &1  \\
               1 &3
           \end{array}\right|=11
        \end{array}\right]\\
        \frac{1}{|\mathrm{det}\Lambda^{-1}|}=4\cdot 3\cdot 5-1\cdot 1\cdot 5-2\cdot 2\cdot 4-3\cdot 3\cdot 3+1\cdot 2\cdot 3+1\cdot 2\cdot 3\\
        =60-5-16-27+6+6=24\\
\Lambda=\frac{1}{24}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
           11  & (-1) & (-7) \\
             (-1) & 11 & 5\\
             (-7) & 5 & 11
        \end{array}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{B \Lambda}=\frac{1}{24}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
            1 & 0& 0 \\
           1  & 0& 1\\
           0& 1& 1
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
           11  & (-1) & (-7) \\
             (-1) & 11 & 5\\
             (-7) & 5 & 11
        \end{array}\right]\\
        =\frac{1}{24}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
          1\cdot 11+0\cdot (-1)+0\cdot (-7)   & 1\cdot (-1)+0\cdot 11+0\cdot 5& 1\cdot (-7)+0\cdot 5+0\cdot 11 \\
          1\cdot 11+0\cdot (-1)+1\cdot (-7)   & 1\cdot (-1)+0\cdot 11+1\cdot 5& 1\cdot (-7)+0\cdot 5+1\cdot 11\\
          0\cdot 11+1\cdot (-1)+1\cdot (-7) & 0\cdot (-1)+1\cdot 11+1\cdot 5 &0\cdot (-7)+1\cdot 5+1\cdot 11
        \end{array}\right]\\
        =\frac{1}{24}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
            11 & (-1) & (-7) \\
            4 & 4 & 4\\
            (-8) & 16 & 16
        \end{array}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{B\Lambda B^{T}}=\frac{1}{24}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
            11 & (-1) & (-7) \\
            4 & 4 & 4\\
            (-8) & 16 & 16
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
           1  & 1&0 \\
           0  &0 &1\\
           0& 1&1
        \end{array}\right]\\
        =\frac{1}{24}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
            11\cdot 1+(-1)\cdot 0+(-7)\cdot 0 & 11\cdot 1+(-1)\cdot 0+(-7)\cdot 1& 11\cdot 0+(-1)\cdot 1+(-7)\cdot 1 \\
            4\cdot 1+4\cdot 0+4\cdot 0 & 4\cdot 1+4\cdot 0+4\cdot 1& 4\cdot 0+4\cdot 1+4\cdot 1\\
            (-8)\cdot 1+16\cdot 0+16\cdot 0& (-8)\cdot 1+16\cdot 0+16\cdot 1& (-8)\cdot 0+16\cdot 1+16\cdot 1
        \end{array}\right]\\
        =\frac{1}{24}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
            11 & 4& (-8) \\
           4  & 8& 8\\
           (-8)& 8& 32
        \end{array}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mathrm{E}(U|V=0,W=1)=\mu_{x}+\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
             1-\mu_{v}\\
             0-\mu_{w}
        \end{array}\right]\\
        \Sigma_{12}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
             4&(-8)
        \end{array}\right]\\
        \Sigma_{21}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
             4  \\
             (-8) 
        \end{array}\right]\\
        \Sigma_{22}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
            8 & 8 \\
           8  & 32
        \end{array}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Sigma_{22}^{-1}=\frac{1}{8\cdot 32-8\cdot 8}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
            32 & -8 \\
           -8  & 8
        \end{array}\right]=\frac{1}{3\cdot 8\cdot 8}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
            32 & -8 \\
           -8  & 8
        \end{array}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
        \mathrm{E}(U|V=1,W=0)=0+\frac{1}{3\cdot 8\cdot 8}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
             4&(-8)
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
            32 & -8 \\
           -8  & 8
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
             1-\mu_{v}\\
             0-\mu_{w}
        \end{array}\right]\\
 =\frac{1}{3\cdot 8\cdot 8}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
            4\cdot 32+(-8)\cdot (-8) & 4\cdot (-8)+(-8)\cdot 8 
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
             1-\mu_{v}\\
             0-\mu_{w}
        \end{array}\right]\\
=\frac{1}{3\cdot 8\cdot 8}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
            192 &(-96) 
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
             1-0\\
             0-0
        \end{array}\right]\\
        =\frac{1}{192}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
           192\cdot 1 + (-96)\cdot 0
        \end{array}\right]=1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
24\cdot \mathrm{Var}(U|V=1,W=0)=\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}=11-\frac{1}{192}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
           192 + (-96)
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
             4  \\
             (-8) 
        \end{array}\right]\\
=11-\frac{1}{192}\left[\begin{array}{c}
           192\cdot 4+(-96)\cdot (-8)  
        \end{array}\right]\\
        =11-\frac{1}{192}\left[\begin{array}{c}
             1536
        \end{array}\right]=11-8=3\\
\mathrm{Var}(U|V=1,W=0)=\frac{3}{24}=\frac{1}{8}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
X|X+Y=1,Y+Z=0\in N(1,\frac{1}{8})
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

Is this correct? My book gives me a different answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track, but you're working way too hard on this one.  Sooner or later algebraic and numerical mistakes will creep into even the best calculations.  A good strategy is to minimize the amount calculation: the *Principle of Mathematical Laziness.*  A key element of this principle is *just-in-time computation:* don't do any work until you have to.  The following solution illustrates these ideas.

---

You have seen the virtue of changing variables.  Keeping $X$ (whose conditional distribution we wish to compute), let the two new variables be

$$U = Y+Z,\ V = X+Z.$$

Consequently, looking ahead to the next step, note that the original variables can be expressed as

$$Y = U-V+X,\ Z=V-X.$$

You also recognized the need to compute the Jacobian of this transformation.  Using the method I have described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154298/919 this is almost trivial:

$$\left|\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z\right| = \left|\mathrm{d}x\wedge  \mathrm{d}(u-v+x)\wedge \mathrm{d}(v-x)\right| = \left|\mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}u\, \mathrm{d}v\right|.$$

This leaves only the argument of the exponential, into which we need to substitute

$$y = u-v+x,\ z = v-x$$

and then set $u=0$ and $v=1.$  Focusing on the argument of the exponential (and ignoring the necessary division by $2$), this can be performed by visual inspection of the coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$ and then, as always with Normal distributions, completing the square:

$$\begin{aligned}
4x^{2}&+3y^{2}+5z^{2}+2xy+6xz+4zy\\ &= 4x^2 + 3(u-v+x)^2 + \cdots + 4(v-x)(u-v+x)\\
&= (4+3+5+2-6-4)x^2 \\&+ (0-6-10-2+6+8)x \\&+ \text{constants}\\
&= 4x^2 - 4x + \text{constants} \\
&= \frac{(x-1/2)^2}{(1/2)^2}+\text{some constant}.
\end{aligned}$$

We know the conditional distribution will be Normal with some mean $\mu$ and some standard deviation $\sigma$, which means this quadratic part will take the form $(x-\mu)^2/\sigma^2$ plus some constant.  Comparing with the foregoing, you can read off the values $\mu=1/2$ and $\sigma=1/2.$

You will, of course, wish to check this work: but I hope you find this to be much less effort than checking your original calculations.