# Distribution of the ratio of Dirichlet/Gamma variates

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, ratio, dirichlet-distribution

It can be seen that the following random variates have the same distribution:

1. $\frac{X_1 + X_3}{X_2 + X_3}$, where $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \sim \text{Dirichlet} (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$
2. $\frac{Y_1 + Y_3}{Y_2 + Y_3}$, where $(Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, Y_3) \sim \text{Dirichlet} (\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$
3. $\frac{Z_1 + Z_3}{Z_2 + Z_3}$, where the $(Z_i)_i$ are independent and $Z_i \sim \text{Gamma}(k = \alpha_i, \theta = 1)$

**Question: does this distribution have a name?** Has it been studied somewhere in the literature? Were it not for $X_1$ in the numerator, it seems that this would be a Beta-Prime distribution.

Comment: There is no $Y_0$ in your second formula.

Comment: @StephanKolassa that's intentional.

Comment: Once you know that [Dirichlet distributions arise as ratios of Gamma variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36093), everything fits together.  Such combinations of variables like $(X_1+X_3,X_2+X_3)$ have been used to formulate multivariate families of correlated Gamma distributions, suggesting one direction to search.

Comment: @whuber thanks, unfortunately I'm not seeing how this gets me farther than the equivalence between 1., 2. and 3.

Comment: I had hoped it would give you a way of searching for an answer to your question about a name, as well as explaining to the other commenter what is going on.

Comment: @whuber thanks, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that yes, this distribution has indeed been studied:

Lee, Ru-Ying, Burt S. Holland, and John A. Flueck. ["Distribution of a ratio of correlated gamma random variables."](https://doi.org/10.1137/0136025) *SIAM Journal on Applied Mathematics* 36.2 (1979): 304-320.

The authors have not given a name to this 3-parameters family of distribution. They frame this in the context of the *Cherian-David-Fix* bivarate structure.

I would personally suggest to call this a *Dirichlet Process Mass Ratio* distribution, denoted $\text{DPMR}(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$, reflecting the fact that such a random variable  is the ratio of (random) probability masses given to two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ by a Dirichlet Process. $\alpha_1$ corresponds to $S_1-S_2$, $\alpha_2$ to $S_2-S_1$, and $\alpha_3$ to $S_1 \cap S_2$, consistently with writing these indices in binary (1 -> `01`, 2 -> `10`, 3 -> `11`).