Proof change of variables for multivariate PDF
While reading Normalizing Flows, I got familiar with change of variables for 1-dimensional distributions. If $Z$ is a random variable and $X=f(Z)$ is monotone with inverse $Z = h(X) = f^{-1}(X)$, then we have:
$$
p_X(x) = \frac{\partial P(X \le x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P(Z \le z)}{\partial z}\big|\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\big| = p_Z\big(h(x)\big)\big|h'(x)\big|
$$
There is a very similar formula for a random vector $Z$ and $X=\mathbf{f}(Z)$.
$$
p_X(\mathbf{x}) = p_Z\big(\mathbf{f}^{-1}(\mathbf{x})\big)\Big| \det\big( \frac{\partial\mathbf{f}^{-1}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \big) \Big|
$$
But I can't prove it formally. Are there any suggestions? Thanks!

This notation and formula are from the mid-19th century.  For a slightly more modern approach (late 19th century!) see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154298/919.

@whuber There is no benefit in using differential forms in Euclidean spaces. In order to compute anything with differential forms, you are just expanding out the determinant anyway, and they get more mechanically tedious to use. Indeed, differential forms were avoided until mathematicians realized that calculus generalizes to manifolds. Differential forms are just a mechanism which are coherent on different local charts. The benefit of using forms would come in from random variables which are supported on a manifold, and they are entirely necessary, but in $\mathbb{R}^n$ they are not required.

@NicolasBourbaki Your perspective is appreciated, but unlike what you suggest, I have found huge benefits from using differential algebra, both conceptually and computationally.  Of course YMMV and it's useful to have many techniques available.

Are you okay with a "heuristic" proof? Let $Y = f(X)$. The probability that $Y = x$ in a small infinitesmial interval around $x$ will be equal to the probability that  $X = f^{-1}(x)$ in that small infinitesmial interval. However, when applying the function $f^{-1}$ the size of that infinitesmial interval increases at the rate measured by the derivative so you multiply by $|(f^{-1})'(x)|$. After all the derivative is the measure of the rate of change in a function we shrink the interval down to zero.
More generally, if $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are random vectors then the probability that $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{x}$ in a small neighborhood (not interval) of $\mathbf{x}$ is equal to the probability that $\mathbf{X} = f^{-1}(\mathbf{x})$. However, you need to multiply by how much the neighborhood rescales by.
Here you need to know two facts. First, the Jacobian, the multivariable analogy of the derivative, which we again denote by $(f^{-1})'$ is now an $n\times n$ matrix. The matrix is the linear map which transforms the function $f$ locally.
Second, from linear algebra, the determinant of the matrix measures the rate of distortion of that linear transformation. When you put all of it together the formula makes a lot of heuristic sense.
Proving it formally is going to be harder, and the complexity will depend on how formal you want to go.

A "heuristic proof" from Nicolas Bourbaki? Heresy!
